# Modifying JSON Data Structure in Data Factory

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a JSON file that I need to move to Cosmos DB.  I currently have a PowerShell script that will modify this file to a proper format to be used in a Data Flow or Copy activity in Azure Data Factory.  However, I was wondering if there is a way to do all these modification in Azure Data Factory without using the Powershell script.

The Powershell script can manipulate a 50MB file in a matter of seconds.  I would also like a similar speeds if we build something directly in Azure Data Factory.

Without the modification, I get a error because of the "@" sign.  Furthermore, if I want to use companyId as my partition key, it is not allowed because it is inside of an array.

The current JSON file looks similar to the below:

```
{
    "Extract": {
        "consumptionInfo": {
            "Name": "Test Stuff",
            "createdOnTimestamp": "20200101161521Z",
            "Version": "1.0",
            "extractType": "Incremental",
            "extractDate": "20200101113514Z"
        },
        "company": [{
            "company": {
                "@action": "create",
                "companyId": "xxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-aaaa-bbbbbbbbbbbb",
                "Status": "1",
                "StatusName": "1 - Test - Calendar"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I would like to be converted to the below:

```
{
    "action": "create",
    "companyId": "xxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-aaaa-bbbbbbbbbbbb",
    "Status": "1",
    "StatusName": "1 - Test - Calendar"
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bill Donofrio, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new data flow that reads in your JSON file. Add a Select transformation to choose the properties you wish to send to CosmosDB. If some of those properties are embedded inside of an array, then first use Flatten. You can also use the Select transformation rename "@action" to "action".

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory or Data Flow doesn't works well with nested JSON file. Per my experience, the workaround may be a little complexed but works well:

1. Source 1 + [Flatten active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten) 1 to flat the data in key 'Extract'.
2. Source 2(same with source 1) + Flatten active 2 to flat the data in
   key 'company'.
3. Add a [Union active 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-union) in source 1 flow to join the data after
   flatten active 2
4. create a [Dervied Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) to filter the column/key you want after
   union active1
5. Then create the Azure Cosmos DB as sink.

The Data flow overview should like this:
[image]